# Stored procedures and functions is not updating for Entity Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2013

I work with database first Entity Framework & LINQ in Visual Studio 2013.

When i write stored procedures and change them, i used to update Entity Data Model from database by choosing stored procedure updating option.

It is weird that the 'import selected stored procedures and functions into the entity model' option comes disabled so I cannot choose stored procedures and functions for updating model anymore..

Can you please help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to import stored procedure and functions into the model when they're *new*. So when there are no new ones the option is disabled.

This doesn't mean that, as you seem to suspect, EF doesn't update *existing* stored procedures and functions. It does.